# How to change the color of ContentPresenter of a radio button

Tags: silverlight, xaml, coding-style, radio-button

I am making a radio button style in XAML and I want to change the color of the Content Presenter(text) if the state is pressed. I hope it is possible.

Here is my code:

```
<Style x:Key="NavButtonsStyle1" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF448DCA"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddleBackground"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#7FFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#CCFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#F2FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddleBackground"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#6BFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#C6FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#EAFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#F4FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckIcon"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Selected_Copy" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter_Copy1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Unselected_Copy" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter_Copy" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentFocusVisualElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Ellipse x:Name="Background" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Height="14" Margin="1" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Width="14"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="BackgroundOverlay" Fill="#FFC4DBEE" Height="14" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="1" Width="14"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="BoxMiddleBackground" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="10" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="1" Width="10"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="BoxMiddle" Height="10" StrokeThickness="1" Width="10">
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.64,0.88" StartPoint="0.62,0.15">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.013"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#EAFFFFFF" Offset="0.603"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#D8FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                                <Ellipse.Stroke>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".5,1" StartPoint=".5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Ellipse.Stroke>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="BoxMiddleLine" Height="10" Opacity=".2" Stroke="#FF333333" StrokeThickness="1" Width="10"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="CheckIcon" Fill="#FF333333" Height="4" Opacity="0" Width="4"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Height="14" Opacity="0" Width="14"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ContentFocusVisualElement" Height="16" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Width="16"/>
                            <Grid x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" ToolTipService.PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                        <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                    <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </EventTrigger>
                                        </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <Ellipse Height="14" Stroke="#FFDB000C" StrokeThickness="1" Width="14"/>
                                <Ellipse Fill="#FFDB000C" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="4" Margin="0,-2,-1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="4"/>
                                <Ellipse Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="10" Margin="0,-5,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Path x:Name="Selected" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Data="M0,0 L170,0 L170,0.12136253 L170.08366,0.083332568 L178.269,50 L170,99.778702 L170,100 L0,100 z" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Stroke="Snow" StrokeThickness="2" d:IsHidden="True">
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1F1F1F" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.05"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF9B9B9B" Offset="0.947"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF818181"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                        <Path x:Name="Unselected" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Data="M0,0 L170,0 L170,0.12136253 L170.08366,0.083332568 L178.269,50 L170,99.778702 L170,100 L0,100 z" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Stroke="Snow" StrokeThickness="2">
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1F1F1F" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFCAC9C9" Offset="0.05"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7C7A7A" Offset="0.947"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF818181"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,0,10" Source="Edit.png"/>
                        <Path x:Name="Unselected_Copy" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Data="M0,0 L170,0 L170,0.12136253 L170.08366,0.083332568 L178.269,50 L170,99.778702 L170,100 L0,100 z" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Stroke="Snow" StrokeThickness="2" Opacity="0">
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1F1F1F" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFCAC9C9" Offset="0.05"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7C7A7A" Offset="0.947"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF818181"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter_Copy" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Path x:Name="Selected_Copy" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Data="M0,0 L170,0 L170,0.12136253 L170.08366,0.083332568 L178.269,50 L170,99.778702 L170,100 L0,100 z" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Stroke="Snow" StrokeThickness="2" Opacity="0" d:IsHidden="True">
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1F1F1F" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.05"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF9B9B9B" Offset="0.947"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF818181"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter_Copy1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,0,10" Source="Edit.png" Opacity="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either change the ContentPresenter to a ContentControl or, replace the ContentPresenter with a TextBlock and set its Text TemplateBinding to Content.